# Jquery .load issue when dealing with Iframes?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, load

I use successfully the following code to load asynchronously some content into a web page:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery("#boxasync").load("box.php", "",
            function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if(textStatus == 'error') {
                    jQuery('#boxasync').html('There was an error making the AJAX request');
                }});
```

Now when trying to use the same code to load common sharebuttons (tweetme, facebook, digg) the webpage content is wiped out and the the browser is set in a sort of wait-state.

I have discovered that those sharebuttons sport some code embedding iframes (and javascript too, I'm afraid).

Could this be the reason jQuery .load is failing?

Comment: .load() uses XMLHttpRequest, so if you're doing a cross domain request (which looks like it's the case), your response will be blank. Lots of info about this to be found on stack overflow so won't repeat it here.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Is there a way to achive async load of those sharebuttons in your opinion?

Comment: I'll digg around. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common for scripts designed for third-party invocation to use `document.write()` to output their content.

This is fine when loaded in a straight `<script>` element in the main page source, as at this point `document.write` merely adds output to the page at the position of the `<script>` that caused it. But it's no good after the page as loaded: there's no ‘write position’ for the content to end up in, so what JS does instead is to infer you meant to call `document.open()` to write a completely new document before calling `write`. This destroys the current page content.

You can try to ‘cheat’ third-party scripts by making your own function that overrides `document.write`, redirecting the strings passed to it to a variable which can then be output to the page using `innerHTML`/`html()`. But you may be better off extracting the guts of what the scripts do and doing it yourself. Reducing reliance on third-party scripts is a good thing because every time you use one, you're giving that party complete cross-site-scripting access into your security context.

In any case you should never use `.load()` or `.html()` to load content that includes `<script>`, as the results are highly unreliable.

Comment: What should be used to load something that may include <script>?

Comment: There is no reliable way. jQuery tries, but fails, to work around the cross-browser problems here. Keep your scripts and your markup separate. Try to keep script code completely static and execute it as and when you need to; if you really need to execute script returned from the server, use `eval` and keep it separate from returned markup.